# SSRS reports not working in browser, architecture mismatch between Driver and Application

Tags: postgresql, reporting-services, database-connection

I have built some SSRS reports that work fine running in Visual Studio:

[image]

However when trying to run the reports in the web browser I get the following error message:

[image]

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Cannot create a connection to data source 'DataSource1'. 
(rsErrorOpeningConnection)
ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN 
contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
```

The data source for my reports that works in Visual Studio is a system DSN 32-bit connection (tiingo_32bit):

[image]

When I test the connection it seems to work fine:

[image]

This solution and set of reports is based on a Postgresql database which is running on a raspberry pi on my network. None of these reports work.

I also have a MS SQL Server database on my local machine which is also running the SSRS server. The reports I have built from those MS SQL databases work fine in both visual studio and the browser:

[image]

Is there something special to be able to use a Postgresql database with SSRS reports?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is (or at least has been in the past) a 32-bit application so it can't work with the 64-bit connection. That said, [Visual Studio 2022 is 64-bit](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022/) so you could try that to see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you Deirdre for your comment. Since Visual Studio is 32-bit and that is the main tool for creating SSRS I would think the SSRS server should be compatible with the 32-bit connections. Any idea about the error message when running the reports from the browser?