# SSRS Report not working in browser while using ODBC connection type

Tags: reporting-services, odbc, dsn

I am having a problem running a SSRS report in the web browser. I have the same type of issue as the one describe here :[SSRS reports not working in browser, architecture mismatch between Driver and Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70796223/ssrs-reports-not-working-in-browser-architecture-mismatch-between-driver-and-ap).

In my case I use MYSQL ODBC Driver (System DSN created in both 32 bit and 64 bit) to have access to a MariaDB and create a Data Source.
Everything works fine in Visual Studio. But when I deploy the report I have this error:

> ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

From what I've read about this error, it's most likely related to the driver not being installed on the machine or not using the correct Bit. In my case I exclude this, I have the System DSN in 32 and 64 bit.

Any idea what may be the problem here?

Comment: " it's most likely related to the driver not being installed on the machine" Can we assume you mean the server and not the machine you are running it from as it's the server running SSRS that needs the correct drivers installing.

Comment: Oh then maybe that is why it is not working. What I did is that I installed the ODBC from this site: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/ then went to control panel --> Admin Tools -->ODBC Data Sources and then I added a System DSN and used to create the data source in SSRS and it works fine. Does it mean that I have to install it on the server in order for it to work in the browser? Can you guide me on how to do so? Thanks

Comment: You will need to ask a new question, probably on ServerFault rather than StackOverflow as it's not strictly a programming issue. However, I would guess you will have to get onto the server that hosts SSRS and install it in the same manner you did on your PC. Remember that when you access a report from SSRS web portal, it's the server that does all the work and then just returns the results to the browser so you can see it.